# Would it be possibile to advance Beamer at the level of the HTML presentations?

Tags: beamer, presentations, javascript

I use mostly Reveal.js for my presentations and lately I learned Beamer. As far as I see you can reproduce almost anything from a HTML pres. in Beamer with a little work, except for the **animations/transitions** and the **interactions** area (dragging things on the screen, manipulate the presentation in real time, etc.).

This is where the full power of HTML5 and js comes to fruition and the PDF format shows its limit.

So my question is: is this a technical limit of LaTeX or the PDF format which is impossible to overcome, or at least in theory we can expect a Beamer successor that will bring LaTeX presentations up to par with HTML/js?

I already know the `animate` package and that you can use js code into PDFs, but the js support for PDFs seems to be very limited, and the `animate` package is not very user-friendly to work with and sometimes gives unpredictable results.

**Edit:** To give you an example of a presentation that I don't think could be done in Beamer/LaTeX, take a look at: http://vizzuality.github.io/rollingstonesmap

Specifically look at how you can zoom in real-time on the background map to reveal content, move things around, etc.

Comment: You certainly don't need any transitions. And you can use `media9` for animations.

Comment: The pdf-format is limited, it is a format to read information. As @yo' pointed out, you can use animation and similar stuff including JS into pdf.

Comment: Have you guys ever tried to use js into a pdf pres.? It is extremely complicated and often unpredictable. Also, many js libraries (like jquery, D3, etc.) cannot be included into a PDF, so the support is very very limited, it seems more on the level of a proof of concept to me. With "transitions" I don't mean "slide transitions" but "content transitions" that are necessary when you need to move things around, otherwise everything looks extremely unnatural.

Comment: This is defined by Adobe unfortunately. So most viewers won't even be able to replay them. There are tools like [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) that works on the PDF for you. Otherwise, there is not much hope for it I'm afraid.\

Comment: impressive provides only slide transitions, not content transitions. As of today the vast majority of viewers already provides slide transitions, so that's not a very big gain.

Comment: Do you mean stuff like `onframe` `pause` and `only`? Please ave a look at section 9 of the documentation.

Comment: @Johannes_B no. Those things control the appearance of items. With "content transitions". I mean something that let's you freely move things around into a canvas, like jquery does for js elements and the `animate` package tries to do for LaTeX. Unfortunately with `animate` the transitions can olnly be predefined and not in real time as is for jquery. Please look at the pres. I linked and try to reproduce the free zooming on the background with Beamer.

Comment: As the pdf-format is supposed to be kind of static and preserve the content, i think you don't want to use it. May i ask why you want to do it with LaTeX? I know for a fact that even `TeXperts` don't necessarily use LaTeX for presentations.

Comment: @Johannes_B because the html format has other shortcomings (which would probably be OT to discuss here), so I'd like to know from experts if it will technically feasible to have the full power of js in Beamer or if Beamer has already reached its limit and can't be developed more (at least in this direction).

Comment: I think what people are saying is that this is not really a limitation of `beamer`, but of PDF. So while `beamer` might be developed further - or another package might be developed differently - you are not going to get the kinds of dynamic content you're discussing so long as PDF is specified in the way it is. And there is some doubt, I guess, whether a future PDF spec is likely to change this so long as Adobe conceive of PDF as an essentially archival format.

Comment: Not relevant to the technical question, but I'd be very wary of any form of 'interactive' slides of this form. My experience doing academic talks and lectures is that what works best is something akin to classic printed slides: a few very good images and the ability to actually _talk_ well!

Comment: @JosephWright: But there much more people who can't talk well (or don't know their subject) and so need fancy stuff and special effect to hide behind ;-). (But not everything that moves is of this kind. I saw lately a (beamer) presentation with a 3d image of a building you could move around - that was very neat and much better than a lot of 2d-plans.)

Comment: @JosephWright but the "academic talk" scenario is not the only one where you need to present something... I don't think it's fair to consider only one scenario, one specific audience, etc.

Comment: @EdTeX Well yes, but `beamer` specifically is about academic talks, _etc._ TeX isn't the right tool for everything, and if I was doing say a flashy product launch I'd choose a visual tool (probably KeyNote). (One for chat in any case: not directly linked to the question at hand.)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a partial answer...
Some requirements in the question are not easy to get. I will focus in some easy ones :) !

Some of the requirements are beamer independent.

In normal situations I like beamer to produce just the pdf pages and define
the  presentation dynamics later (**pdf viewer vs presentation tool** (thank you @fran)).

Presentation tools (like [`impressive`](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/)) provide:

1. options to define transitions, time bars, slide bars;
2. commands (hot keys, mouse events) for zooming, highlighting, spotlight
3. scripting...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a single latex beamer source to produce both pdf and
reveal.js output. The html for reveal.js generation is done through HeVeA.
You can embed any html source in the LaTeX sources, so the reveal.js (html5+js) has no limitations.

I have a sample presentation that describes how this can be done, with pdf and reveal.js outputs, based on a single beamer source.

See below links.

http://www.by-star.net/PLPC/180038

http://web.by-star.net/lcnt/PLPC/180038/current/pres/PLPC-180038-pres.html#/

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.